# Angular 5 input keyup.enter errors and slow down app

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have implemented the chat functionality with Socket.JS, Node.JS and Angular 5.

On input field I have added debounce delay, but the issue is on typing message the app slow down and even when we start typing the text is shown on input on a delay which is making app look bad. Please check the attached images:

[image: Error while typing on input textbox]

Comment: Unable to understand what you are doing inside the keyup event.

Comment: If you want to detect a value change on the input field, please go ahead with reactive form valuechange method which is an observable, you can subscribe to the event and try to achieve the same. https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/ this is much faster than keyup focusout events

Comment: Hi @AnoopMc I'm sending message on "Enter" key pressed. That's the reason I used (keyup.enter). Thanks!

Comment: Okay, how about using form submit still? You could disable default actions with preventdefault() method.

Comment: Hi @AnoopMc, I tried form also but still same issue. Thanks!